Saml2AuthenticationException: No relying party registration found
What could be the cause for this error ? as this happens this works in localhost but when deployed to server it fails.
org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.Saml2AuthenticationException: No relying party registration found
        at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)

